# custom color property in panel draw layout

Tags: python, scripting, customization

I have my panel with draw definition. And want define color for BGL in panel.
I know that Color class exists in blender, but how to use it? How to create custom color property for my panel?[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The graphical representation is determined by the subtype field which is set in this example to 'COLOR'.

```
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
...

object_color = FloatVectorProperty(  
   name="object_color",
   subtype='COLOR',
   default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
   min=0.0, max=1.0,
   description="color picker"
   )
```

- Documentation on [custom properties](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_66a_release/bpy.props.html),
- Nice [tutorial on addons](http://michelanders.blogspot.nl/p/creating-blender-26-python-add-on.html)

Comment: Don't forget to specify `min` and `max` for color properties (edited above). You may also be interested in `subtype='COLOR_GAMMA'` with gamma correction to the color. Set `size=4` for RGB + Alpha.